# DB table constraint to compare other table values

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Say i have two tables:

Table1 (id, name, type(enum - main,sub))

Table2 (id, name, table1_id (F.K, reference to Table1 id))

While inserting into table Table2, should be able to insert only if "name" is equal to "main".

Will i be able to do this defining constraints on Table2?

If yes, how will i do?

Comment: Does https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-16-introducing-check-constraint/ help?

Comment: *should be able to insert only if "name" is equal to "main".* You mean `table.type = 'main'`? No. Check constraint can test current record only and cannot refer on another records or another tables. Trigger logic only.

Comment: @Akina, Ok. Constraints work only for current records. How about the performance with triggers?

Comment: I find this a confused question. There is no way using an FK in table2 to restrict name to 'main'(or looked at another way a subset of type in table1. If you wanted the name to be restricted to main or sub then you could do that by creating an FK on name referencing type. If that is not the case then you have to enum name or create a trigger.

Comment: *How about the performance with triggers?* Performance with triggers is worse then performance without triggers. How much worse - a practical test will show.

Comment: @Salmon, the example which i gave is to make understand my requirement. Wanted to know, is something like this is possible or not.

Comment: @Akina, Got answer to my question. Wanted to know, will i be able to achieve using the use-case asked using constraints. Cleared with the doubt.

Comment: @Pooja If an entity stored in table2 may refer to an entity stored in table1 with the type of 'main' only then think does the entities from table1 of different types are the same entity? perhaps it makes sense to divide table1? onto table11 with the entities of type 'main' and table12 with the rest, referred to table11, and table2 will refer to table11 only without additional constraints?

Comment: Sounds like something to do in app code.